# VBA If a specific cell in Sheet1 contains data > 0, put a specific code on Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I'm given a set of data on SHEET1 that may look something like this:

```
        B      C      D       E       F       G     H (Codes)
31    21957    0     3707     0     1996     356   3422
32       13    0       13     0       13      10   3455
33     4543    0      767     0      413     423   3446
34     6119    0     1033     0      556    1549   3603
35    12238    0     2066     0     1113      56   3703
```

Each row of data corresponds to a certain code (see Codes column above). For example, any data in row 31 greater than 0 has the code 34-22. Row 32 is 34-55, row 33 is 34-46, row 34 is 36-03, and row 35 is 37-03.

How can I write a macro that can have this result on SHEET2 based on the data above:

```
     AG   AH   AI   AJ
57    3    4    2    2  (based on data in cell B31 of Sheet1)
58    3    4    5    5  (based on data in cell B32 of Sheet1)
59    3    4    4    6  (based on data in cell B33 of Sheet1)
60    3    6    0    3  (based on data in cell B34 of Sheet1)
61    3    7    0    3  (based on data in cell B35 of Sheet1)
62    3    4    2    2  (based on data in cell D31 of Sheet1)
63    3    4    5    5  (based on data in cell D32 of Sheet1)
```

and so on and so forth...

So far, I have this:

```
Dim x As Integer, DestLast As Long, HoldVal As String
 If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B31").Value > 0 Then
        DestLast = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("AG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If DestLast < 57 Then DestLast = 57
        HoldVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H31").Value
        For x = 1 To 4
            Dim columnNumber2 As Integer
            columnNumber2 = 32 + x
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(DestLast, columnNumber2).Value = Mid(HoldVal, x, 1)
        Next x
    End If
```

The problem with this is that I would have to write this macro for every cell (B31:G35). Is there an easier way of doing this?

Please let me know if I'm missing any information or if you have any questions about what I'm asking!

Comment: It isn't at all clear how your Sheet2 data is a function of Sheet1. You mention it as somehow depending on columns B and D but then seem to be simply pulling digits from strings in the column labeled Codes in a way which seems to be quite unrelated to columns B and D. In any event -- you need to have at least some VBA code to show and then ask focused questions about how to improve it.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm sorry I wasn't more specific, I just added the code I have so far. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (not tested -- I'm taking it for granted that the body of the loop, which you essentially wrote, does what you want it to do for cell B31 and am illustrating how to modify it to apply to the entire range of cells, in the column by column manner you seem to want)

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For j = 2 To 7 'Columns B to G
    For i = 31 To 35
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,j).Value > 0 Then
                DestLast = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("AG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                If DestLast < 57 Then DestLast = 57
                HoldVal = Trim(Str(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,8).Value))
                For x = 1 To 4
                    Dim columnNumber2 As Integer
                    columnNumber2 = 32 + x
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(DestLast, columnNumber2).Value = Mid(HoldVal, x, 1)
                Next x
            End If
    Next i    
Next j
```

Comment: When I tried to run it, it came up with "error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error" on `HoldVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(i,8).Value`

Comment: It ran without any errors, but nothing showed up on Sheet2 :(

Comment: try it now -- I converted HoldVal to a string and trimmed off white space. If you had declared it a string at first it might have been easier, but works now.